# Getting Raid details via the Softlayer api

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking for a way to verify the raid card and number of drives in my softlayer bare metal server. I can get the type of card, but I am wondering if there is a way to pull the Raid level and the drives in the Raid (if more than one raid). Is this something that is stored in the initial order that I may be able to pull out? My current call to get the adapter details:

```
[
    {
        "hardwareComponentModel": {
            "capacity": "16",
            "description": "71605 RAID Card",
            "hardwareGenericComponentModel": {
                "capacity": "16",
                "description": "RAID CARD",
                "hardwareComponentType": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "keyName": "DRIVE_CONTROLLER",
                    "type": "Drive Controller",
                    "typeParentId": 3
                },
                "hardwareComponentTypeId": 5,
                "id": 283,
                "units": "Drives",
                "upgradePriority": 7
            },
            "hardwareGenericComponentModelId": 283,
            "id": 777,
            "longDescription": "Adaptec / 71605 / SATA/SAS RAID",
            "manufacturer": "Adaptec",
            "name": "71605",
            "version": "SATA/SAS RAID"
        },
        "hardwareComponentModelId": 777,
        "hardwareId": 296328,
        "id": 2612500,
        "modifyDate": "2016-02-23T21:22:38-06:00",
        "name": "0",
        "serialNumber": "4b061355adb",
        "serviceProviderId": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This request may help you:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Configuration_Storage_Group_Array_Type/getAllObjects
Method: GET
```

**Reference:**

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Configuration_Storage_Group_Array_Type/getAllObjects

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Nope that information cannot be retrieved via API. you need to log on to the machine and see the current raid configuration for the machine. The information is stored in the initial order, but is not available via API.